# xpages viewpanel pager combined with search not defaulting to the first page once user used the pager to navigate to the second,third,fourth etc. page

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a viewpanel that I am using the "Search in view results" feature.  The view has a pager.  The scoped variable that I use for the search is null initially and the user has an option to choose from a list to create a search.  The initial null search brings back about 1000 records and the user can use a page selector to scroll through the entries if they wish.  If the user chooses say page 5 and then creates a search, the pager headers show up but no search results.  In order to see the search results the user has to manually click on "first", then the pager resets and the results of the search appear.

I saw a solution in [ViewPanel filter by StartKeys...but pager don't Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299677/viewpanel-filter-by-startkeys-but-pager-dont-update).  However, I cannot use getAllEntriesByKey because I am returning the results of a search not a filter.
Here is the code, stripped down to the basics.  In my application the user can create a search with up to 4 terms.
Thanks,
---Lisa&

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:table>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td><xp:comboBox id="TeacherComboBox" value="#{viewScope.TeacherComboBox}">
                            <xp:selectItems id="selectItems9">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ""}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:selectItems id="selectItems10">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dbName = session.getCurrentDatabase();
var view = ("CampusCodes");
var CampusList = @Unique(@DbColumn(dbName,view,1));
return CampusList}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                        </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td><xp:button id="button14" styleClass="BlueButtonSmall" value="Apply Search">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler17">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.TeacherSearchFormula = null;

var TeacherSearchFormula = null;
var Campus = null;

if (!!viewScope.TeacherComboBox) {
    Campus = '[CampusNum]' + ' CONTAINS ' + viewScope.TeacherComboBox;
};


if (!!Campus) {
    TeacherSearchFormula = Campus;
};

if (!!TeacherSearchFormula) {
    viewScope.TeacherSearchFormula = TeacherSearchFormula;
    print("viewScope.TeacherSearchFormula = ",viewScope.TeacherSearchFormula);
    viewScope.ErrorLabel4T = "Search did not return any teachers.";
} else {
    var varAlert = "Please choose some filters."
    var al = "alert('"+ varAlert +"')";
    view.postScript(al);
}}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button><xp:button id="button15" styleClass="BlueButtonSmall" value="Clear Search">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler19">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("TeacherComboBox").setValue("");
viewScope.TeacherSearchFormula = null;
viewScope.TeacherComboBox = null;
}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:pager xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1"
                            for="viewPanel1" partialRefresh="true">
                            <xp:pagerControl type="First"
                                id="pagerControl1">
                            </xp:pagerControl>
                            <xp:pagerControl type="Next"
                                id="pagerControl2">
                            </xp:pagerControl>
                            <xp:pagerControl type="Group"
                                id="pagerControl3">
                            </xp:pagerControl>
                            <xp:pagerControl type="Previous"
                                id="pagerControl4">
                            </xp:pagerControl>
                            <xp:pagerControl type="Last"
                                id="pagerControl5">
                            </xp:pagerControl>
                        </xp:pager>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="view1"
                            viewName="NISDTeacher" sortColumn="$1"
                            search="#{javascript:viewScope.TeacherSearchFormula}">
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="CampusNum"
                        id="viewColumn1">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="CampusNum"
                            id="viewColumnHeader1">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$1" id="viewColumn2">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="TeacherFull"
                            id="viewColumnHeader2">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="CampusName"
                        id="viewColumn3">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="CampusName"
                            id="viewColumnHeader3">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="TeacherEnumber"
                        id="viewColumn4">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="TeacherEnumber"
                            id="viewColumnHeader4">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="TeacherPTitle"
                        id="viewColumn5">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="TeacherPTitle"
                            id="viewColumnHeader5">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="RatingText"
                        id="viewColumn6">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="RatingText"
                            id="viewColumnHeader6">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="RatingNum"
                        id="viewColumn7">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="RatingNum"
                            id="viewColumnHeader7">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Comments"
                        id="viewColumn8">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Comments"
                            id="viewColumnHeader8">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                </xp:viewPanel></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table></xp:view>
```

Comment: This happens. You need to [reset pager to first page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409683/how-to-get-pager-back-to-first-page-on-click-event) when user clicks the search button.

Comment: Thank you.  Hopefully, the code will work for a regular viewpanel as well. I will work with the code later this week.